# jquery multiple deferred chaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013

This is not working at all for me. Basically, if I step through it, it performs in the order where I have breakpoints (BREAKPOINT1, BREAKPOINT2, etc)

Due the way I am required to do sharepoint development at the moment, everything must be asynchronous. Loading data for one edit list item results in maybe 10-12 asynchronous calls. So I have chains several layers deep everywhere. This is the one that is completely breaking the functionality.

EDIT- What I want to happen. I want to call get children, get the group id's from a list, call getgroupname and get the group names for all id's (as many as 50) and then dump the array contents into a hidden field so when I update the list, it doesn't go and create a new record for each of these group ids as it would on a new list item. So when I click "update" it will grab the id's and create a new listitem for any group not present in the hidden field. This is a parent/child relationship, each group that is selected results in a new list item, but I only need one per group, not multiple.

I need to know how to fix this chain so that it returns my group names to the hidden field. I'm just having issues getting there and am hoping someone can spot my breakdown in logic.

```js
function getchildren(id) {
  var retval = [];
  var url = "call to sharepoint 2013 url";
  var ajaxPromise = restfulAPICall(url); //inside of this includes return $.ajax
  ajaxPromise.then(function (data) {
     $.each(data.d.results, function (i, v) {
       var def = new $.Deferred();
       getGroupname(v.Assigned_x0020_ToId.results[0]).done( //BREAKPOINT4 - multiple hits
         function (val) {
            def.resolve(val); //BREAKPOINT5
         }
       )
       .done(function () {
         reval.push(def); //BREAKPOINT6 (then back to 5, etc for # of results)
       });
     });
  });
  return $.when.apply(undefined, retval).promise(); //BREAKPOINT2
}

function getGroupName(v) {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var groups = ctx.get_web().get_siteGroups();
  var groupname = groups.getById(v);
  ctx.load(groupname);
  ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    d.resolve(groupname.get_title());
  }, 
  function (sender, err) {
    d.reject(err);
  });
  return d.promise();
}

//somewhere else
if (!isChild) {
  getChildren(id).then(function (val) { //BREAKPOINT1
    $('#children').val(val); //BREAKPOINT3 - value blank
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="children" />
```

Comment: So what do you actually want to happen? Please edit your question to contain an actual question.

Comment: Sure, will do now.

Comment: I think Breakpoint2 is the problem.  The return is going to execute before retval has anything in it.  You don't populate retval until breakpoint6.  I'm not sure the purpose of so many deferreds.  Seems to me you could move breakpoint3 where breakpoint4 occurs, and remove breakpoint4,5,6.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I have to loop through the results to get group id, then send each group id to sharepoint to get back a group name, then dump the entire result into the hidden field. Though, one option may be just appending the result onto the hidden field so that I can't move 3 into that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the heart of the matter is that, in `getChildren`, `return $.when.apply(undefined, retval).promise();` executes immediately, before any of your async code has had time to do anything, and so `retval` remains an empty array and the returned promise immediately resolves to an empty array. The fix might look something like this, or at least this should point you in the right direction:

```
function getChildren() {
  var deferredResult = $.Deferred();
  var url = "call to sharepoint 2013 url";
  var ajaxPromise = restfulAPICall(url);
  ajaxPromise.then(function (data) {
    var retval = [];
    $.each(data.d.results, function (i, v) {
      retval.push(getGroupName(v.Assigned_x0020_ToId.results[0]));
    });
    // Only resolve promise returned from getChildren() once you have actually processed all the group names. Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) converts arguments to real array
    $.when.apply(undefined, retval).then(function() {
      deferredResult.resolve(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    });
  });

  return deferredResult.promise();
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzzmd1fa/2/), simplified from your originally provided code, with some mocked AJAX data to see if this might be what you are looking for...

Comment: I see, I think, where I was going wrong there. The deferred stuff.. simple enough to implement when you got one or two, but when you are a dozen deep it becomes obvious how much you may not understand what it's actually doing. Thanks for the assistance, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Cliff In fact now that I look at it with relatively fresh eyes, you could probably directly store the `getGroupName` return value (supposedly a promise to be resolved to the group name) in `retval`, without having to use the intermediate `var def = new $.Deferred()`.